# Error with dates when filling a datatable

Tags: sqlite, vb6

I am trying to fill a datatable in vb using SQLiteDataAdapter from a SQLITE database.  There are 3 fields in the table that contain dates and they appear as either recent dates or "1899-12-30" .  The Fill command generates a "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error.  I cannot find a date entry that does not look valid, except "1899-12-30", is this a valid date?

Any other thoughts would be appreciated.
Brad

Comment: Have you tried inserting the date as "18991230"?  It also mentions that it isn't a valid date time so you might need to add a 00:00:00 on to it.  Have a look at your other dates, could you swap the month and the day around and still get a valid date.

Comment: vb6 is NOT vb.net. Please [edit] your question with the correct tags, and while you're at it, show some code and perhaps a table structure.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I set the value back to (null) and am dealing with this rather than try and negotiate the "1899-12-30" date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is 'yes'. I built a table with the three possible ways of storing dates, thus:

```
CREATE TABLE `JustDate` ( `Date_1` INTEGER, `Date_2` TEXT, `Date_3` REAL )
```

Then I populated each of those fields in one record with the value you suspect.

[image]

And then I did a trial query against the fields to see if sqlite would treat them as proper dates.

[image]